# "thread-local storage not supported for this target", suitable #ifdef?

Tags: c++, gcc, portability, thread-local

Since every compiler has its own version of thread local storage, I ended up creating a macro for it. The only problem now is GCC (with pthreads turned off), which gives me:

"thread-local storage not supported for this target"

Fair enough, given that pthreads are actually turned off in this case. The question is, is there a generic way of detecting this using some macro e.g. #ifdef __GCC_XXX_NO_THREADS_XXX ?

EDIT: See the accepted answer below. Also, here's my lazy solution:

```
$ touch test.c
$ gcc -E -dM test.c > out.1
$ gcc -pthread -E -dM test.c > out.2
$ diff out.*
28a29
> #define _REENTRANT 1
```

This is on Mac OS X. I am not sure if it's portable or anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compile command line either has `-lpthread` or not:  You could include a `-DHAVE_PTHREADS` there as well.

If you really want GCC/ELF specific runtime dectection, you could resort to weak refs:

```
#include <pthread.h>

extern void *pthread_getspecific(pthread_key_t key) __attribute__ ((weak));

int
main()
{
    if (pthread_getspecific)
        printf("have pthreads\n");
    else
        printf("no pthreads\n");
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
$ gcc -o x x.c
$ ./x
no pthreads
$ gcc -o x x.c -lpthread
$ ./x
have pthreads
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about __attribute__(weak). And yes, obviously you are right in that I could use a macro. My question is more of the lazy kind :), but also because I'm curious about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use autoconf for your project you might find [ax_tls.m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_tls.html) useful.

Comment: But I don't (luckily) :). For the record, I use cmake, but I would prefer to have it straight in the header file if possible, since I'm just hacking together a small prototype right now...

Comment: grep /usr/include suggests that __GTHREADS is used internally in a number of header files, but that looks pretty unreliable and not intended for public use.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, I tried my diff thing on an Ubuntu machine. Gave the same result (i.e. _REENTRANT). Reading the header, it looks like more if __GTHREADS has to do with if gcc was compiled with thread support or not. But I don't know... I should probably get back to what I was doing instead :)